# How to create MetaData in Teamsite

Tags: metadata, opentext, teamsite

I got a task where I need to create 3-4 new MetaData field. On the click of a button, the specific article will be populated with the new MetaData values.

I need to know that in Teamsite how I will be able to create the MetaDataField.

Comment: Hello, Welcome to SO, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask